# ms access dynamically change label on report

Tags: ms-access, report

I am printing a production ticket as a report using the following code:

```
Dim strCriteria As String
 strCriteria = "SELECT [PkgSize] & chr$(32) & [PkgUnit] AS Pkg, tblProducts.ProductID, tblProducts.ProductPrintName, tblProducts.Grade, " _
            & " tblCustomers.CompanyName, tblOrderDetails.ODEPriority, chr$(33) & chr$(70) & [tblProducts].[ProductID] & [tblCustomers].[ID] & chr$(33)as Expr1" _
            & " FROM tblCustomers INNER JOIN (tblOrders INNER JOIN (tblProducts INNER JOIN tblOrderDetails ON " _
            & " tblProducts.ProductID = tblOrderDetails.ODEProductFK) ON tblOrders.ORDOrderID = tblOrderDetails.ODEOrderID) ON " _
            & " tblCustomers.ID = tblOrders.ORDCustomerID " _
            & " WHERE (((tblProducts.ProductID)=[Forms]![frmInventoryTransfersManual]![cboTransferProductID]) " _
            & " AND ((tblOrderDetails.ODEPriority)= " & varPriority & ") AND (([tblOrderDetails]![ODEQtyOrdered]-[tblOrderDetails]![ODEQtyProduced])>0))"

 DoCmd.OpenReport "rptProductPaperLabelTCTRlogo", acViewPreview, , , , strCriteria
```

In the report I have:

```
Private Sub Report_Open(Cancel As Integer)
    Me.RecordSource = Me.OpenArgs
End Sub
```

The various text boxes on the report use the following as their Control Sources: Grade, Expr1, ProductPrintName, Pkg, and CompanyName. (Expr1 produces a barcode for scanning the ticket.)

It works perfectly.  However, I also need to print a label or, could be, a text box to form a border on the report.  This label/textbox will be a color assigned to CompanyName. Therefore, the ticket can be seen quickly and know who the customer is just by knowing the color of this label/textbox.

Can anyone help me to change the color of a label/text box on the report dependent on the company name.  We have about 20 different customers.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Add a color attribute to the table definition for the customer table. Add that color attribute to the recordsource of the form.  Use that color to set the backcolor property of the control on the report in the appropriate eventhandler of the form, probably onChange?

Comment: Somewhat new to Access - I will give that a try.  Thanks

Comment: I have my border as a text box.  I have added the colorAttribute field to the company table.  I have added the reference to that field in the Select stmt.   And of course all I get in the text box is the string value of the color attribute. You suggested an event handler.  I do not know which one to use because there doesn't seem to be an appropriate one to put code into (based on my understanding of these).  The text box has no change/update events.

Comment: On change event of the form

Comment: excuse my ignorance but in the 'event' tab of the report property sheet there is no 'on change' option.  Am I looking in the wrong place?

Comment: I don't know how your report is structured but you should have a detail section -- there is an event that will fire when each detail record is formatted called onFormat and there is an event that fires when the record is painted called  onPaint.

Comment: thanks for pointing me in the right direction.  Some of access is confusing if you don't know where to look.

Comment: @LesProgrammer It does take practice, no doubt. Thanks for hanging with me.